# DXA 2.0 client-side cache using RedisCluster fails

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, cache, cil, redis

Trying to configure DXA 2.0 client-side cache using redisCluster but it fails to run our app, it throws

> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisMovedDataException: MOVED

It seems that DXA client-side is only compatible with `JedisPool` instead of `JedisCluster`

Is there a way we can use Redis cluster for client-side caching?